# Find if groups of characters are repeated in a string in python

Tags: python, string

I am a beginner and I want to know that how to determine if a string contains characters which are re-occuring in a pattern.

Example: "aabcdabcdabcdabcd"
Here four characters - 'abcd' are getting repeated.
But I do not know that how many characters are getting repeated.

The pattern is not certain. I do not know it. "aabcdabcdabcdabcd" is just an example.
The pattern can be in any order
Please help.
My code is :

I don't actually know the string!

```
s1=str("aabcdabcdabcd")
x=0
z=""
for i in range (1,len(s1)):
    z=s1[i:i+5]
    s1.replace(z,"",1)
    if z in s1:
          x+=1
    if x!=0:
          print "yes":
    else:
          print "no"
```

The above program works only for the given string. I want it to be able to evaluate any string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: So you want to detect some kind of cycle with possibly something before or after? You want the longest cycle?

Comment: Can you explain your question in more detail? Do you want to find the specific pattern "abcd" or any pattern? If so what is the minimum length of a pattern?

Comment: do you just want the count of each char that is repeated?

Comment: I just want to know if a group of chars is repeated.

Comment: so how many times abcd are repeated consecutively?

Comment: Why is it `abcd` and not `bcda`? Its also repeated.

Comment: Its not a certain pattern. In fact, I don't know the pattern!
It keeps on changing.
Example: If the chars in a string are: 000110011001100110011 then 0011 is repeated.
and if 111000110001100011 is the string then 00011 is repeated.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh, what about overlapping strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find all repeats of letters - then you can filter the sets you want.

```
cstr = 'aabcdabcdabcdabcd'
dd = {}
for ii, ch in enumerate(cstr):
    # find all sequences of 3-6 characters long
    for jj in range(3,7):
        wrd = cstr[ii:ii+jj]
        if not len(wrd) == jj:
            break

        dd.setdefault(wrd, 0)
        dd[wrd] += 1

# find any "word" that occurs more than once
for k, v in dd.iteritems():
    if v > 2:
        print k, v
```

Answer (score 0):

In Natural Language Processing these are called ngrams, for most common NLP tasks the nltk library is very useful:

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
from collections import Counter

s = 'aabcdabcdabcdabcd'
max_ngram = 5
minimum_count = 2
ngrams_found = Counter()

for x in range(max_ngram-1):
    ngrams_found += Counter(["".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams(s, x+minimum_count)])
for key, val in ngrams_found.items():
    if val < minimum_count:
        del ngrams_found[key]
    else:
        print(key, val)
```

The Counter object also allows you to print the x most common ngrams:

```
ngrams_found.most_common(5)
```

Comment: Not sure this is what the user asked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to Python myself, and one of the things I found most exciting initially was that it's very easy to start working with the characters which make up strings.

To answer your problem, I would start with:

```
for letter in string:
    # work through the string and check for repeated patterns
```

Comment: I do not want to count the repetetion of letters, I want to find if a group of letters is repeated.